# Русский эквивалент enjoyment - есть ли такое слово (словосочетание)?

Tags: выбор-слов

Удовольствие, которые вы получаете от действия, или опыта.

Нужно определение или короткое словосочетание.

Comment: Pleasure)))))))

Comment: _Удовлетворение_ не подойдёт?

Comment: "Радость труда" - было такое пропагандистское понятие :).